# How to get Span collection by id in Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

Is there a method in watir to get list of all the span collection by id. I can traverse the span tags only by index and one item at a time.
i want to get the entire collection of the span tags and loop through it.

```
    irb(main):060:0> ie.span(:id =>/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl132_lblSubject/).text
=> "30 stuff"

irb(main):065:0> ie.span(:id =>/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl/).exists?
=> true
irb(main):073:0> spans=ie.span(:id =>/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl/ ,:index=>3)
=> #<Watir::Span: located: false; {:id=>/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl/, :index=>3, :tag_name=>"span"}>
irb(main):074:0> spans.text
=> "Well, morning."
irb(main):075:0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate. Write the following code

```
ie.spans(:id =>/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl/).each do |span|
  p span.text
end
```

It will print all the span's text which is matching your id.